# How to replace \" with " using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

I have an API that returns an HTML string but it has some extra characters in the API and I want to replace that with something else.

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0\">
```

I want to replace `\"` with  `"` using that using `replace` so that it becomes

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

What is the regex `string.replace()` for doing the above task?

Comment: What is the source of your input string on line 2 above?  Those backslashes look to be escaping characters for the literal double quotes which follow them.  That is, the backslashes aren't really "there."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `\\` into your regexp

```js
var text = '<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0\">';

var result  = text.replace(/\\"/g, '"');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have to escape the \ with another \

```
yourstring.replace(/\\"/, '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this without RegEx

```
<?php
$a = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0\">";
$b = str_replace('\"', '"', $a);
var_dump($b);
```